# Mongodb cursor to Json

Tags: mongodb, cursor

So my problem is that I cant push a result of findOne() method to array in document.

For example, I want to add another user to some array (project participants) like this :

```
var user =db.users.findOne({_id:"123456"}) 
db.projects.update({_id:'abcde'},{$set:{$push:{participants:user}}})
```

how can I fix that ?

Comment: You can't embed the `$push` operator within the `$set` operator, just use the `$push` on its own like `db.projects.update({_id: 'abcde'},{$push:{participants:user}})`

Comment: Its pushes this object : DBQuery: db.users -> { "_id" : ObjectId("56dca006095081e") }

not the real json

Answer (score 0):

You need your update query like so:

```
db.test.update({
    _id: 'abcde'
},
{
    $push: {
        participants: { name: 'Bob'}
    }
})
```